# Picture Gallery & Message Forum

Tags: php, cms, looking-for-a-script, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

Any suggestions for both an Open Source Picture Gallery and also for a relatively simple Message Forum (only low number of users), PHP/Python/Ruby/MySQL or anything else which is available.

What I am primarily looking for are applications which can easily be incorporated into our existing website (same header, menu, floatin footer, quick linkd panel etc.) rather than as a full separate webpage.

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to incorporate a simple message forum and gallery in your website, probably the best is to find forum and gallery modules for your content management system. There's some great Gallery and Forum modules for Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla and other. Do you use a CMS? If not, consider moving your website to one. You will have slightly more work now, but certainly less hassle later.

Comment: Thanks Osvaldo but I didn't want to go to the complexity of a full CMS system.  Apart from the Image Gallery and Message Forum the rest of the site is going to be relatively static.

Comment: As you want simplicity and adding independent Open Source Galleries and Forums can become even more complex, I suggest you check if Flickr galleries (example: http://www.flickr.com/groups/blackwhite/pool/show/ ) and Facebook or Twitter streams.